# maven: Failed to execute goal on project

Tags: java, maven

This is the error I am getting in maven.

```
 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project eDisplayData-module-socketIoServer: Co
uld not resolve dependencies for project com.volvocars.vcc.and:eDisplayData-modu
le-socketIoServer:jar:1.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies for [com.volv
ocars.vcc.and:eDisplayData-module-services:jar:RELEASE (compile), com.ford.vcc.g
ent.tclient:tclient-vcg-messaging:jar:RELEASE (compile), com.corundumstudio.sock
etio:netty-socketio:jar:1.7.8 (compile), io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.0.32.Final
 (compile), com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:jar:0.4.2 (test), com.fasterxml.j
ackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.4.4 (compile), com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson
-databind:jar:2.4.4 (compile), com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:ja
r:2.4.4 (compile), javassist:javassist:jar:3.12.1.GA (compile), org.slf4j:slf4j-
api:jar:1.7.11 (compile), org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.11 (runtime), log4j:lo
g4j:jar:1.2.17 (runtime), com.ford.vcc.gent.base:uFramework:jar:RELEASE (compile
), com.ford.vcc.gent.base:uCommonLib:jar:RELEASE (provided), com.ford.vcc.gent.s
ys:uUtilities-test:jar:RELEASE (test), com.volvocars.vcc.and:uCommonIntegrationT
esting:jar:RELEASE (test)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.fasterxml
.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.6.3: Could not transfer artifact com.fasterxml.
jackson.core:jackson-core:pom:2.6.3 from/to mirror (http://gensvl4002.gen.volvoc
ars.net:8080/repository/mirror): Failed to transfer file: http://gensvl4002.gen.
volvocars.net:8080/repository/mirror/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.6
.3/jackson-core-2.6.3.pom. Return code is: 500, ReasonPhrase:Unable to fetch art
ifact resource.. -> [Help 1]
```

I have tried mvn clean install, mvn clean, clean build and all but they didn't work.

Comment: It seems as if the highlighted dependencies are missing from your repository or you have not setup the repository properly.

Answer (score 1):

```
Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.fasterxml
.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.6.3: Could not transfer artifact com.fasterxml.
jackson.core:jackson-core:pom:2.6.3 from/to mirror (http://gensvl4002.gen.volvoc
ars.net:8080/repository/mirror)
```

The problem is that your settings.xml try to download jackson-core from the following mirror : http://gensvl4002.gen.volvoc
    ars.net:8080/repository/mirror
Update your settings.xml to also mirror maven repo central (jackson is available there http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.fasterxml.jackson.core%22%20AND%20a%3A%22jackson-databind%22)

You could also proxy the maven repo central on http://gensvl4002.gen.volvocars.net:8080 (as long as it have access to internet)[image]